# How can i display image in P-fileupload primeng programatically?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using `primeng p-fileupload` to upload images, but I want to do programmatically to preview the image onUpload event, after uploading I am getting the image URL path as

`blob:https://primeng-breadcrumb-demo-ntijjo.stackblitz.io/1c2dadec-e61b-42b7-8c6b-c56d342fb136`, but the image is not showing ...so after inspecting the image its displaying

`unsafe:blob:https://primeng-breadcrumb-demo-ntijjo.stackblitz.io/6a7a24d7-33fc-4738-b7f8-93b4b6007123`

I am attaching the stack blitz URL for reference:-
https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-breadcrumb-demo-ntijjo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Please help me with these issues.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FileReader API to read the contents of the file and then set it as an  src.

For example:

```
onUpload(e## Heading ##vent) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e: any) => {
        // Set image src
        this.imageSrc = e.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.files[0]);
}
```

Then in your template:

```
<img [src]="imageSrc" />
```